# window.open is dropping the = in my parameter list on my home page only

Tags: javascript

I'm calling javascript to append a parameter to my URL prior to calling window.open. This code works perfectly on every page but my homepage. On the homepage, the "=" is dropped in the parameter list. Any ideas why?

On every page but homepage, the window opens as expected:
https://dev.mysite.com/?m_=myModal0

On the homepage, the window opens like this:
https://dev.mysite.com/?m_myModal0

```
<a href="<?php echo $my_link; ?>" target="_self" onclick="OpenModal('myModal<?php echo $count;?>')" class="btn get_code" id="get_code<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php esc_html_e('get code', 'comre');?></a> 

<script>
function OpenModal(modalid){
    var win;    
    //event.preventDefault();

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("m_") > -1) {
        var reexp = new RegExp(/m_=(.*?)$/);
        var url = window.location.toString();
        var newUrl = url.replace(reexp, ("m_=" + modalid));
        win = window.open(newUrl, '_blank');
    } 
    else {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
           win = window.open(document.URL+"&m_="+modalid, '_blank');
       }
       else {
           win = window.open(document.URL+"?m_="+modalid, '_blank');
       }
    } 

    win.focus();
    return true;
}
</script>
```

There are no errors shown in the console.

Comment: It might be some server-side redirect… or not. More importantly, are you sure you want an empty parameter `m_=` followed by a hash `#myModal`? Or should there be a `modalid = encodeURIComponent(modalid)` at the beginning of `OpenModal` or equivalent in order to get `?m_=%23myModal0`?

Comment: The hash is definitely janky and unnecessary, as is the dash on the end, I just haven't cleaned up the code yet to remove it. Your suggestion would be a good one if I decide I'm too lazy to remove it.

Comment: Just cleaned up the code so I wouldn't leave the janky in there.

Comment: You still have `("m_=#" + modalid)` and such, though. Should it be `("m_=%23" + modalid)`? To be clear, the `m_` parameter is empty because `#` has special meaning in a URL.

Comment: Good grief. Yes that was wrong too. Took the hashtag off completely and added it in the correct place in the show modal code and halelujah that fixed the problem! Thank you!!

Comment: Be kind to your users: don't use `window.open`, create a normal link to a relative `href` in Javascript, add a `target="_blank"`, append it to the document, click it, and remove it from the document again. That way the browser sees a normal navigation action, and will do everything it does for any other URL (like add a browsing history entry, not have popup blocking kick in, etc)

Comment: I would consider using [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) to extract/modify your search parameters.

Comment: Thanks Amy! I definitely started down that path but after checking GA saw we have quite a bit of IE traffic and it isn't implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

Be nice to your users: don't force them to allow popups on your website by insisting on `window.open`. Instead, create a normal navigation link, and click that. So instead of this:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
...
window.open(url);
```

use this:

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = "none";
  a.href = url;
  a.target = "_blank";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body..removeChild(a);
}

...

var url = ...
openInNewTab(url);
```

Is that more code? Sure, but it's a one-time function declaration so not something worth caring about: call . But it also means opening a URL like any other, with the browser doing everything it normally does when people navigate from page to page.

Comment: That doesn't quite fit my use case but I do appreciate the help Mike!

Comment: Noted. But unless you're writing an electron app, your usecase should never be `window.open`. Especially not for smaller-sized-window popouts etc. That's what overlay modals are for ;)